# Bidual of $B(Y,\ell_2^n)$

Tags: banach-spaces

How do I prove that $B(Y,\ell_2^n)^{**}$ is isometrically isomorphic to $B(Y^{**},\ell_2^n)$?

Comment: Presumably you are asking for a proof that a particular "natural" map between these two spaces is an isometric isomorphism. Could you tell us what this map is, or is the definition of the map part of what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: @ Choi! We have a natural isometric isomorphic identification $(Y\hat{\otimes}\ell_2^n)^{*}=B(Y,\ell_2^n).$ Therefore, we want to show the following identification $(Y\hat{\otimes}\ell_2^n)^{***}=B(Y^{**},\ell_2^n).$

Comment: @Choi! Therefore, we want to show that  $(Y\hat{\otimes}\ell_2^n)^{***}=(Y^{**}\hat{\otimes}\ell_2^n)^{*}.$

Comment: Here $\hat{\otimes}$ is the projective tensor product.  If $Y$ is finite dimensional our claim is true by duality of projective and injective tensor norms.

Comment: @Choi1 I ask the following question is $(X\hat{\otimes}\ell_2^n)^{*}=X^{*}{\otimes}_{\epsilon}\ell_2^n$ for any Bnach space $X$ ? where $\otimes_\epsilon$ is the injective tensor product. the duality relation is the natural duality relation between injective and projective tensor product.

Comment: There is a very nice proof in Bill Johnson's answer to my question https://mathoverflow.net/q/145412 (the situation seems a bit different as it considers $B(X,Y)$ with $X$ finite dimensional, but this is the same as $B(Y,\ell_2^n) = B(\ell_2^n,Y^*)$).

Comment: Translated in this context, the proof becomes: 1. If $\ell_2^n$ is replaced by $\ell_\infty^N$ the answer is easy because $B(Y,\ell_\infty^N) = \ell_\infty^N(Y^*)$. 2. It follows that $B(Y,X)^{**}=B(Y^{**},X)$ for every subspace of $\ell_\infty^N$. 3. By approximation, the equality follows for every finite-dimensional $X$.

Comment: @Mikael! I would look into that. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Mikael! How do i deduce 2. from 1. Is it true that $B(Y,X)=B(Y,\ell_\infty^N),$ for any subspace $X$ of $\ell_\infty^N$?

Comment: I was merely asking because some **other** people seem to have voted to close your question as "unclear what you are asking". There is no need for the exclamation marks, unless there is some subtle feature of the "ping" notification.

Comment: Also, you seem to have missed my point, which is that when you ask if two spaces are isomorphic, you should really specify which map is supposed to be an isomorphism. Think of the question: "is the James space $J$ isomorphic to its bidual?" The answer is yes, but $J$ is not reflexive, because the *canonical embedding*  of $J$ into $J^{**}$ is not surjective.

Comment: @Choi. My exclamation symbol meant nothing at all!!! Yes. I agree, I was not very clear. But I think on the later posts, I have clarified myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ Choi. See I used '!' symbol for Mikael too.